# SameSite error for third party iframe HTML

Tags: javascript, html, samesite

I am using Venobox (similar to lightbox) on my website which is a third party iframe that I want to load a YouTube video from.

here is the HTML code:

```html
<a class="venobox" data-autoplay="true" data-vbtype="video" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gVvy2ijnqOU">
 <div class="video-gal-box">
  <img src="assets/img/yt_thumbnails/ford_ranger.jpg" alt="">
   <div class="overlay-effect"></div>
    <i class="fab fa-youtube"></i>
 </div>
</a>
```

Chrome gives me the following warning error which prevents that particular video from loading: 
A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://youtube.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. It has been blocked, as Chrome now only delivers cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.

I have a gallery page setup with 10+ iframes loading a different YouTube video and this only affects 3-4 videos.

Is there something some JavaScript I can include in the HTML page and set SameStite=none to mitigate the issue?

Comment: This site may help you out.. https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592

Answer (score 0):

No. In this context, you cannot affect 3rd part cookies flags.

Comment: is there a way to get around it?